# Como gerar novo código a partir do DBO

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Tenho uma tabela com o nome `Produtos` em que eu inseri 3 produtos para testes. Agora estou montando o formulário de cadastro de produtos e preciso que sempre gere um código de produto sequencial a partir do último id já cadastrado + 1.

O código que fiz é esse, segui a minha lógica mas n está funcionando.

```
    private void GerarNovoCodigo()
    {
        string strCon = "Data Source=MEUPC; Initial Catalog=MEUDB; Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlCon.Open();

        sqlCom.CommandText = "Select max(prod_codigo) + 1  from Produtos";

        txt_prod_cod.Text = Convert.ToString(sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }
```

Comment: A não ser pelo fato que isto é um perigo em ambiente concorrente e que provavelmente deve ter muito código repetido na aplicação, pelo descrito não consegui ver problema. Precisar adicionar mais detalhes.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, leia o guia [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: Aparentemente, o código executa corretamente, qual é o problema enfrentado?

Comment: @bigown Como voce faria para sempre gerar um novo código de forma simples? É uma aplicação básica por enquanto, de cadastro, consulta e movimentação de produtos diversos. Há sim código repetido na aplicação, mas por hora quero fazer funcionar o básico para enxugar depois, visto que estou na fase de aprendizagem ainda. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @JulioBorges O textBox não está recebendo o novo código. Quando executo a aplicação ele carrega em branco.

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho aparece em branco ou aparece sempre 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Elaborei essa resposta apenas para englobar e tentar sanar todas as dúvidas que encontrei na pergunta sobre SQL, inclusive.

#### Vamos falar sobre SQL primeiro...

O que você quer o próprio banco de dados já faz. Para isso, basta marcar o campo da `Key` como [Auto Increment (Identity)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186775.aspx). Feito isso, você não precisa inserir o código no `INSERT`, que o banco faz tudo automático para você.

Um exemplo seria:

```
CREATE TABLE Produtos
(  
 Id int IDENTITY(1,1),  
 Nome varchar (100) 
); 

INSERT INTO Produtos VALUES ('Produto1')
INSERT INTO Produtos VALUES ('Produto2')
```

Feito isso, o banco irá salvar os dados como:

```
Id  | Nome
----------------
1   | Produto1
2   | Produto2
```

Caso queira saber qual será o próximo código, você pode utilizar o código abaix:

```
SELECT isnull(IDENT_CURRENT('Produtos') + IDENT_INCR('Produtos'),1)
```

Esse código irá buscar o último id [IDENT_CURRENT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175098.aspx) e somar com o valor incremental, com o [IDENT_INCR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189795.aspx).

Em seu exemplo você está aumentando mais 1, mas se fosse 2, 3, etc... O `IDENT_INCR()` obtém esse valor da `Key` automaticamente.

#### Solução do problema...

Como já apontado nas demais respostas, basta alterar o [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) pelo [ExecuteScalar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) que resolverá o seu problema.

Caso queira entender um pouco mais a diferença entre os métodos, [este link](http://cbsa.com.br/post/diferencas-entre-executereader-executenonquery-executescalar-quando-usar-e-qual-usar.aspx) explica um pouco sobre eles.

Comment: Muito bom cara! Vou usar identity, visto que parece ser mais correto e seguro, certo?

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho Essa é a forma correta de se fazer isso, tanto os outros bancos de dados além do SQL Server possuem essa função. Existem várias perguntas sobre isso no site, basta [ver este link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsql%5d%20primary%20key)

Answer (score 4):

O problema específico é que o método usado retorna o número de linhas afetadas e não o código gerado. O certo é usar o [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteScalar).

Em casos onde há acesso concorrente (quase sempre tem) pegar um código assim é problemático. Tem que mandar gravar os dados e aí gerar um novo código, caso contrário tem uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

Além disso parece que a aplicação tem bastante código repetido. Não é uma boa ideia enxugar depois, mas isso é com você.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 2):

O método que você está utilizando para executar o SQL (`ExecuteNonQuery()`) é um método utilizado para *inserts* e *updates* e o retorno dele é a quantidade de linhas afetadas conforme descrito na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

Utilize o método `ExecuteScalar()`, que o mesmo irá retornar o que você deseja.

Deverá ficar desta forma:

```
txt_prod_cod.Text = Convert.ToString(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar());
```

[Documentação do `ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx).

Isto pode resolver o seu problema, mais conforme sugerido pelo Maniero essa não é uma boa prática, e provavelmente você deve estar repetindo muito código em sua aplicação, seria bom assim que possível reavaliar a forma de trabalho e verificar melhorias.

Comment: Qual seria uma boa prática para gerar códigos sequenciais? O código repetido na aplicação é só na parte de Conexão com o Banco, vou reavaliar sim, obrigado! Estou praticando POO e C#.

Comment: No meu caso, na maioria das vezes utilizo o auto incremento do próprio SQL Server, criando o campo chave com auto incremento, desta forma, o próprio SQL gerencia essa criação de índices. Caso não seja possível trabalhar com auto incremento, vc pode iniciar a aplicação sem o código e quando o usuário realizar a gravação, no momento em que grava, você busca o novo código. Após a gravação recarrega este novo código na tela.

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho, Já que você está praticando POO e C#, seria uma boa também dar uma estudada em um framework ORM como o EntityFramework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/aa937709.aspx).

Comment: Muito obrigado Júlio, vou pesquisar sobre esse auto incremento, o SQL Server a partir do 2012 faz isso certo? Estou usando-o! Vou estudar sobre entity framework também, agradecido! @JulioBorges

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho, sempre suportou... vide exemplo: http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-campos-auto-incremento-identity-no-sql-server/17974